# Swift3 - Dictionary to JSON String

Tags: json, swift, swift3, nsdictionary

I have the following class (In actual Chat class is NSManagedObject, I simplified it for clarity)

```
import Foundation
class Chat: Hashable {

    public var id: Int32?
    public var token: String?
    public var title: String?

    var hashValue: Int {
        return ObjectIdentifier(self).hashValue
    }

    static func ==(lhs: Chat, rhs: Chat) -> Bool {
        return ObjectIdentifier(lhs) == ObjectIdentifier(rhs)
    }
}
```

Here I am initializing the object and storing it in set (In actual this data is fetched using core-data and the type is always `Set`. hence I tried replicating the same type)

```
let chat1 = Chat()
chat1.id = 1
chat1.token = "aU7nanPu"
chat1.title  = "Chat Title 1"

let chat2 = Chat()
chat2.id = 2
chat2.token = "948dfjh4"
chat2.title  = "Chat Title 2"

let chat3 = Chat()
chat3.id = 3
chat3.token = "1321sjadb"
chat3.title  = "Chat Title 3"

var chats = Set<Chat>()
chats.insert(chat1)
chats.insert(chat2)
chats.insert(chat3)
```

I now want to convert the data to JSON to send it to server for processing. (I am using Alamofire with SwiftyJSON) hence I first converted it to Dictionary using the following code.

```
var resultDict = [Int:Any]()
for (index, chat) in chats.enumerated() {
    var params = ["id" : chat.id!, "token": chat.token!, "title": chat.title!] as [String : Any]
    resultDict[index] = params
}
```

This gave me following output

> [2: ["id": 3, "token": "1321sjadb", "title": "Chat Title 3"], 0:
>   ["id": 1, "token": "aU7nanPu", "title": "Chat Title 1"], 1: ["id": 2,
>   "token": "948dfjh4", "title": "Chat Title 2"]]

I now want to convert this output to JSON. here is what I tried.

```
let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: resultDict, options: .prettyPrinted)
```

This gives me an error which says `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid (non-string) key in JSON dictionary`

My question is, how do I convert `resultDict` variable into valid JSON string format?

PS: In-case if someone wants to play with the code, here is the fiddle: https://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/597833e605543472066ad11e

Comment: The error message is crystal clear: Non-string dictionary keys are not allowed in JSON. And don't *pretty print* the string if it's supposed to be sent to a server. The server doesn't care about aesthetics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe resultDict needs its key to be of type String.

```
 let resultDict = [String:Any]()
```

Just convert the index into a string before adding it to the dictionary

```
 resultDict[String(index)] = params
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `resultDict` is of type `[Int:Any]` and JSONSerialization needs keys to be `strings`
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization/1413636-data for more details.

> how do I convert resultDict variable into valid JSON string format

Try this

```
var resultDict = [String:Any]()
for (index, chat) in chats.enumerated() {
    var params = ["id" : chat.id!, "token": chat.token!, "title": chat.title!] as [String : Any]
    resultDict["\(index)"] = params
}
```

Comment: Working now. Thanks :-)